# How to store defined continents in phpmyadmin as default as defined

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

trying to create a table on my database on phpmyadmin but I need to store the values of continents within this so that the user cannot put or select a random name if that makes sense. Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to do please help out :)
Thanks

[image: Error That I am getting, what am I doing wrong?]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the check constraint in the field continent

```
'continent' VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL CHECK ('continent' IN ('Australia','Asia','Africa','North America','Antarctica','South America','Oceania'));
```

Comment: Or you can also use    
    {'continent' ENUM ('Australia','Asia','Africa','North America','Antarctica','South America','Oceania') NOT NULL}